# Alternative option of object-fit:cover for internet explorer

Tags: html, css

I'm looking an alternative method of the object-fit:cover for the internet explorer, because is not supporting it. Basically I'm using the object-fit:cover for not stretching images inside a div. I look on internet for some solutions but all that I found was solutions to load the image from css instead from img tag like they way I'm doing it. Does anyone has any alternative method of not stretching images inside a div on internet explorerCan anyone help me?

here is a simple code

HTML

```
<div class="grid-image"> 
  <img itemprop="image" alt="TEST" src="images/15.jpg">
</div>
```

CSS

```
.grid-image {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: grey;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 100%;
}

grid-image img {
    object-fit: cover;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ok I solved it with this

HTML

```
<div class="grid-image" style="background-image: url(images/15.jpg);"></div>
```

CSS

```
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
```

Comment: What about IE 7? It doesn't support object-cover and it's for html inline images, not background images.

Comment: This is a solution not for IE7. I'm not focussing on IE7 because of it's market share which is 0.35%

Comment: What about IE8? I did some research and people use IE8 and IE9-10 most.

Comment: If people still use IE 7-10 they can't expect perfection, inform them about their old browser using for example this:
https://browser-update.org/

Answer (score 4):

You can really create an alternative for ie9+ using Modernizr. So you can still using object fit where it's supported. In this example I use jQuery too.

```
if ( ! Modernizr.objectfit ) {
  $('.grid-image').each(function () {
      var $wrapper = $(this),
      imgUrl = $wrapper.find('img').prop('src');
      if (imgUrl) {
         $wrapper
         .css('backgroundImage', 'url(' + imgUrl + ')')
         .addClass('compat-object-fit')
         .children('img').hide();
      }  
   });
 }
```

Obviously if any user wants to browse the web with software from the 20th century he will get a 20th century version of the web. It's like trying to watch the 70mm scenes from Interstellar (or any modern 16:9 film) in a 4:3 tube tv, you won't see all the features of the docking scene.

Comment: Unfortunately Edge is not supporting object-fit as well... so i's not only old browsers issue :/ Why Microsoft, why?
What you showed here is a good solution when you have to use img tag and using background-image is not possible/wanted. Thank you :)

Comment: @miss.emenems object-position is not supported by Safari.. It is not only Microsoft ;-)

Answer (score 2):

My approach will ideally work in all browsers as it a simple **CSS** trick. Please check the images below to see the effect it has.

The approach I took was to position the image inside the container with  **absolute** and then **place it right at the centre** using the combination:

```
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
```

Once it is in the centre, I give to the image,

```
// For vertical blocks (i.e., where height is greater than width)
height: 100%;
width: auto;

// For Horizontal blocks (i.e., where width is greater than height)
height: auto;
width: 100%;
```

This makes the image get the effect of Object-fit:cover.

---

## Here is a demonstration of the above logic.

https://jsfiddle.net/furqan_694/s3xLe1gp/

This logic should work in all browsers.

---

Comment: One of the best suggestions on this topic!!

Comment: ...Although the shortcoming is that once the container proportion get narrower than the image proportions, there'll be empty space.

Comment: Applying 100% to the dimension of image which is smaller and 100% to the dimension which is bigger, makes the image fill all the space of the container.

Does this answer your comment? If not, please share an example to demonstrate the scenario. This will help me understand it better and possibly improve my answer.