# Object fit cover on image within a div

Tags: html, css, slider

Right now i have an image within a div like so :

```
<section class="col-md-12">

    <img src="imagepath/image.jpg"/>

</div>
```

I can use object-fit:cover; for firefox , chrome and the other usefull browsers but this won't work for IE. is there a workaround to make the images look the same as they would look with object-fit:cover;?

ps. i am unable to make the image the background of the parent.

Comment: Tried Googling it?  Found this article which contains an answer using a few lines of CSS and JS: https://medium.com/@primozcigler/neat-trick-for-css-object-fit-fallback-on-edge-and-other-browsers-afbc53bbb2c3#.7mk1npsxu

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Alternative option of object-fit:cover for internet explorer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33473978/alternative-option-of-object-fitcover-for-internet-explorer)

Comment: Use that image as a background image of your section. And apply background-size:cover

Comment: I did google it and the solution on the link you placed does not seem to work for me. also @ArpitSvt my last line sayd that i am unable to make it the background. Martin Parkin the other post gives a solution if you CAN make it a backgorund image.

Comment: ops sorry i didnt read that

Comment: Here's some IE guidance for `object-fit`: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37127590/3597276

Answer (score 0):

**Use it to html**

```
<div id="bg">
  <img src="images/bg.jpg" alt="">
</div>
```

**use it to css**

```
#bg {
  position: fixed; 
  top: -50%; 
  left: -50%; 
  width: 200%; 
  height: 200%;
}
#bg img {
  position: absolute; 
  top: 0; 
  left: 0; 
  right: 0; 
  bottom: 0; 
  margin: auto; 
  min-width: 50%;
  min-height: 50%;
}
```

Comment: This makes it the background of the whole page. i need it to stay within the div since it is a slider so it should stay within a div of about 400px height and 100% width.

Comment: Try to Use div element in top of the id area