# CSS Object-fit is not supported IE

Tags: html, css

I need to stretch the image without distortion:

```
img {
   width: 100%;
   height: 300px;

   object-fit: cover;
}
```

But the **`object-fit`** is not supported in **IE**..
there a way to fix this.

Comment: Are you able to use `background-image` on a `<div>` instead? This will allow you use to `background-size: cover;`.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33473978/alternative-option-of-object-fitcover-for-internet-explorer and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37792720/ie-and-edge-fix-for-object-fit-cover

Comment: As far as I got the best solution is to use background-image on the <div> and the background-size: cover;   You can read more about this here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37793244/10909525