# Fallback solution for object-fit on flexslider

Tags: css, flexslider, object-fit

I am using a flexslider (fixed height of 500px) but have slightly modified it to allow images to display nicely even if they have more than 500px height. Therefore I have added

object-fit: cover;
object-position: center;

to the CSS of the img-Tag.

However this is not supported and the images are stretched in a very ugly way in Internet Explorer. Is there any good fallback solution for IE?

I have already searched on StackOverflow but all the answers were not really satisfying.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one:

CSS

```
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
```

for more details you can refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33473978/alternative-option-of-object-fitcover-for-internet-explorer)